# Finding a Record in Airtable regardless of Case using Advanced Search Formula

Tags: syntax, zapier, airtable

I am using Zapier to find a Record in Airtable as that record will contain information needed in future steps.  I receive the record that I need to retrieve in an all-lowercase format.  The Airtable record is usually Titlecase though not always.  I have done a Formatter Step for Titlecase.  I essentially am trying to create an Advanced Airtable Search Formula to retrieve a matching record regardless of what case it is in.  What I have written is:
    `{Active Project}=IF(LOWER("<Trigger Value>{{35606695__output}}<Trigger Value>"),UPPER("<Trigger Value>{{35606695__output}}<Trigger Value>"),"<Trigger Value>{{35825986__output}}<Trigger Value>")`

The search criteria is to find the record either Lowercase, Uppercase, or Titlecase.  It returns empty even though I know the data matches one of those conditions.  How would I retrieve an Airtable record regardless of it's case?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. I love Airtable, so I'm happy to answer this one for you.

The easiest way to search in a case-insensitive manner is to lowercase everything. I made some guesses about your specific setup, this worked like a charm for me:

```
LOWER({Active Project})=LOWER("<TriggerValue>{{35606695__output}}</TriggerValue>")
```

This should eliminate any formatter steps or other trickery you might have needed. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: The wrapping tags should be an opening and closing tag, with no spaces: `LOWER("<TriggerValue>{{35606695__output}}</TriggerValue>")`

Comment: Based on [this support doc](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218151657-Using-Zapier-s-Multi-Step-Zaps-to-find-and-update-records) it seems like there shouldn't be a space, but the `</ClosingTag>` syntax isn't needed (or won't work?). Honestly I wrote this 3 years ago, but the code as written seems like it worked for me at the time. Was it not working for you?

Comment: Hi @xavdid -- no, it was not working for me. But the code I mentioned (which I found here: https://community.zapier.com/featured-articles-65/how-to-do-a-fuzzy-search-in-airtable-3215) worked. I think the docs are out of date on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the syntax has changed since the above answer was posted, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this, follow this article from Zapier: https://community.zapier.com/featured-articles-65/how-to-do-a-fuzzy-search-in-airtable-3215

Make sure the Search By and Search Value fields are **blank**, then use a `FIND()` formula in the Search Formula field. Contrary to [another help article on Zapier](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218151657#formula), the incoming field value needs to be wrapped in `<TriggerValue></TriggerValue>`. (Note closing tag with /, and no spaces).